# How to find the surface area of a parameterized surface

Tags: cross-product, surface-integrals

> Find the surface area of the following hyperboloid 
>   parameterized by
>
> $$\begin{align}x&=(\cosh{t})(\cos{\theta}) 
> \\ y&=(\cosh{t})(\sin{\theta})
> \\ z&=\sinh{t} \end{align}$$
>
> for
>
> $$\begin{align}0\leq  \,&\theta \leq 2\pi \\
>  -1\leq \,&t\leq 1 \end{align}$$

**My Work**

---

Using the following formula

$$\iint_D\left |\vec{r}_u\times\vec{r}_v\right |du dv.$$

where $u=t$ and $v=\theta$

I wind up with the following cross product:

$$\begin{align} 
&(\sinh(t) \cos(\theta), \sinh(t) \sin(\theta), \cosh(t))\times(-\sin(\theta) \cosh(t), \cos(\theta) \cosh(t), 0)\\
=&-\cos{\theta} \cosh^2{t}, -\cosh^2{t} \sin{\theta}, \cos^2{\theta} \cosh{t} \sinh{t}+\cosh{t} \sin^2{\theta} \sinh{t}
\end{align}$$

so that the surface integral becomes

$$\begin{align} 
&\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{\left|\cos{\theta} \cosh^2{t} \right|^2+\left|\cosh^2{t} \sin{\theta}\right|^2+\left|\cosh{t} \sinh{t} \cos^2{\theta}+\cosh{t} \sin^2{\theta} \sinh{t}\right|^2} dt \, d\theta
\\
=&\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\cosh{t} \sqrt{\cosh^2{t}+\sinh^2{t}} \,dt \, d\theta 
\\\approx &20.0153
\end{align}$$

---

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Yes, ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You can make your life easier by (1) picking out a $\cosh t$ (there are $\cosh t$ in all three terms of the cross product. (2) Simplifying the third coordinate of the cross product a little bit.

Comment: Good eye. I'll attempt to simplify and update my post as needed.

Comment: You are correct (I didn't checked the last no).

Comment: Then $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}\cosh{t} \sqrt{\cosh^2{t}+\sinh^2{t}} \,dt \, d\theta$ Is the correct integral?

Comment: Yes, ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Seems nasty to solve symbolically, but I suppose that's the nature of the beast. Thank you!